# Exibição da Array

Tags: ios, swift

Estou tendo problema em executar o xcode devido o erro abaixo:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell



    cell.CellTitle.text = TitleList[indexPath.row]
    cell.CellDescription.text = DescriptionList[indexPath.row]

    let imagename = UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])
    cell.CellImage.image = imagename

    return cell

}





class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let ImageList = ["Burj.jpg","Eiffel.jpg","Empire.jpg","Kingdomtower.jpg","Taipei.jpg"]

    let TitleList = ["Burj Khalifa","Eiffel Tower","Empire state Building", "Kingdomtower Tower","Taipei 101",]

    let DescriptionList = ["Dubai, UAA","Paris, France","New Youk, USA", "Jeddai, Sauid Arabia","Taipei Taiwan",]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return TitleList.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell



        cell.CellTitle.text = TitleList[indexPath.row]
        cell.CellDescription.text = DescriptionList[indexPath.row]

        let imagename = UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])
        cell.CellImage.image = imagename

        return cell

    }
```

[image: print]

Comment: Execute novamente para provocar o erro e passe o mouse sobre os objetos destacados pelo erro. Deve surgir uma retângulo com uma setinha. Expanda-o para ver o valor do referido objeto. Apenas passe o curso por cima do objeto com calma que poderá ver. Adcione na pergunta o que mostrou os submenus. Normalmente pode ter um NSObject nulo com valores "quebrados" ou simplesmente vazio causados por um dealloc prematuro. O que causa erros do tipo `exec_bad...`

Comment: Você provavelmente não está registrando uma celula com o id `"cell"` na sua tabela, ou então o id que você está usando, é diferente do que foi registrado.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisar definir o **identifier** da TableViewCell no storyboard.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]